# user_signed_in? helper for RefineryCMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, refinerycms

What is Devise `user_signed_in?` method named in RefineryCMS?

I'm using RefineryCMS Core 3.0 and refinerycms-authentication-devise 1.0.

I tried `refinery_user_signed_in?` since the class is `Refinery::User` and the current user helper is `refinery_current_user`. But this gives a NoMethodError.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using RefineryCMS 3.0.1 and `signed_in?`seems to work for checking if a user is logged in.